# Stop a 'worksheet_change' or worksheet_calculate from running

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet heavily laden with code.  There are 'worksheet_change' and 'worksheet_calculate' functions amongst that code. during certain procedures this code runs unnecessarily sometimes when working on this sheet. Is there a line of code that would prevent running the 'worksheet_change' or worksheet_calculate macros?  Kind of a "don't call"?

Comment: there is no specific event to stop the firing of the `worksheet event code`. However, you can write code inside the event procedure to only run for certain conditions, using `If` statements, for example. (`If Not Intersect(Target,Me.Range("A10")) Is Nothing` on `worksheet_change`.

Comment: Got it. Unfortunately that pushes the envelope of my ability

Comment: If you have a specific question of how to do it, edit this question, or post another question with the specific code and situation and your attempts to resolve, and we can help you sort it out. It's *fairly* easy in most cases and just involves some logic :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just set `Application.EnableEvents` to FALSE.

Don't forget to turn it ON back after your processing is completed.

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you Seb!